# How to stop click thought an NSView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, click, nsview, nsbutton

I am making app with cocoa(Mac desktop application). I have a NSButton in background of an NSView. The button is clicked even if any NSView is added later in NSWindow.

How to stop click on a button that is at background any NSView ?

Please give suggestion!!!

Waiting for reply!!!

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add a view above your button, disable your button using

```
 [button setEnabled:FALSE];
```